# How to know what version of ant-contrib.jar to be used

Tags: ant

How to know what version of ant-contrib.jar to be used for the ant versions?
  currently I am adapting my testing environment from ant 1.7.0 to ant 1.9.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The version of `ant-contrib` need bear no particular relation to the version of Ant.  If you already have a version that works with Ant 1.7 it will continue to work under 1.9.